# PySpark - Spark SQL: how to convert timestamp with UTC offset to epoch/unixtime?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I convert a timestamp in the format `2019-08-22T23:57:57-07:00` into unixtime using Spark SQL or PySpark?

The most similar function I know is [`unix_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) it doesn't accept the above time format with UTC offset.

Any suggestion on how I could approach that using preferably Spark SQL or PySpark?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern for [ISO 8601time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) in this case is `XXX`.

So you need to use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` as your format string.

**SparkSQL**

```
spark.sql(
    """select unix_timestamp("2019-08-22T23:57:57-07:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX") 
    AS epoch"""
).show(truncate=False)
#+----------+
#|epoch     |
#+----------+
#|1566543477|
#+----------+
```

**Spark DataFrame**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df = spark.createDataFrame([("2019-08-22T23:57:57-07:00",)], ["timestamp"])
df.withColumn(
    "unixtime", 
    unix_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
).show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------+----------+
#|timestamp                |unixtime  |
#+-------------------------+----------+
#|2019-08-22T23:57:57-07:00|1566543477|
#+-------------------------+----------+
```

---

Note that pyspark is just a wrapper on spark - generally I've found the scala/java docs are more complete than the python ones. It may be helpful in the future.

Comment: that's quite useful actually, I've always found very difficult to find appropriate answers by looking at python documentation too. So this would be the Spark function https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String) which is in fact more informative.